# Manipulating XML data in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, xml

I am currently learning how to use Adobe Illustrator and I am trying to find a XML editor in Illustrator so that I can see how the data changes when I manipulate something. I know that in Inkscape there is a XML editor as shown below:

[image: XML Editor in Inkscape]

Is there something similar in Illustrator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for Windows using Notepad++, but I assume also possible on a Mac with a text editor. Depending on the text editor, you may need to manually reload the file each time you make a change.

1. Save your Illustrator document as an SVG (which is a kind of XML document), close the document, then open the SVG file Illustrator using *File > Open*
2. Open the SVG file in a text editor. I used Notepad++ in Windows for this.
3. When you make a change in the SVG in Illustrator, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save.
4. Click on the Notepad++ window and the application will prompt you to reload the file.

Example

[image]

Comment: Thank you, so an inbuilt editor does not come with Illustrator?

Comment: @PitR. There's no built in XML editor in Illustrator. Also note that unlike Inkscape, Illustrator's native file format is not SVG, so this is only a workaround.

Comment: Ok thanks for the information.